# Converting pixels to coordinates on a Mapbox map

Tags: maps, gis, mapbox

I have the lat and lon coordinates to a location on a Mapbox map. The map is set to zoom level 15 and is of bearing 30 degrees. I need to travel +500px horizontally and +300px vertically as the map is displayed on the screen. How do I work out what the destination is in lat and lon coordinates?

I need to do this calculation (and many like it) in a ruby script.

Whilst I've found some information describing how to achieve the reverse of what I want its difficult for me to understand how it works and thus I can't reverse the calculations.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

There's a method named `project` and `unproject`.

`project` converts `LngLat` into pixel and `unproject` converts pixel into `LngLat`.

You can use something like:

```js
const currentCenterPixel = map.project(map.getCenter());
currentCenterPixel.x += 500;
currentCenterPixel.y += 300;
map.once("idle", () => {
    map.panTo(map.unproject(currentCenterPixel));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cs09g/q3x1ohun/8/